# How To Supress ArgumentOutOfRangeException when SelectedValue does not exist in dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, objectdatasource

I have a dropdownlist which uses a objectdatasource to populate. The dataset returned is a list of active locations. We do not delete data, so we do a soft delete using a bDeleted column in the table.

In some cases when populating the ddl, I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException error when binding the SelectedValue because a location may have been deactivated, and is not returned in the list.

It seems to me there should be a way to supress this, and just not select a value.

I liked the answer given in another post suggesting adding an entry manually in red but I'm not sure where/how to do this. Do I need to setup an event handler on the code page to trap this error. Is that too late?

Any help/suggestions would be appreceiated.

Thanks
Patrick

Comment: That means you allow to "delete" locations although they are still in use? Looks like a bug. All depending objects should be "deleted" too.

Comment: my point is that the record is not physically removed from the table. If by bug you mean that any location id's in any related tables are not updated to say null, then yes. In this case the related record should not be bDeleted, but rather the iLocationId must be either updated to null, or the user would need to update this field the next time the reocrd is opened in the ui. Which is why i would like to be able to trap the SelectedValue binding event and either continue, or provide further logic. Unfortunatly MS has decided for me by not implementing an event handler for this.

Comment: @user: i meant that you should have avoided that somebody can "delete" a location that is still in use or to "delete" the related records too(flag them as deleted like `bDeleted`). You shouldn't use exceptions to handle the normal behaviour. You should change the SelectCommand for the DropDownList to get also the locations that are "deleted" but also still in use somewhere. Then you can check if the location is deleted and apply a different css-class on the deleted ListItems(Locations). `DropDownList1.Items[1].Attributes.Add("class", "deleted");`
Edit: Made an answer out of this comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its a good practice to suppress exceptions. You can always do a FindByText or FindByValue on drop down and if it exists only set the selected value.

```
Combobox.FindByText(someText).Selected = true;
```

or

```
Combobox.FindByValue(someValue).Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have avoided that somebody can "delete" a location that is still in use or to "delete" the related records too(flag them as deleted like `bDeleted`).

You shouldn't use exceptions to handle the normal behaviour.

You should change the SelectCommand for the DropDownList to get also the locations that are "deleted" but also still in use somewhere. Then you can check if the location is deleted and apply a different css-class on the deleted ListItems(Locations):

`DropDownList1.Items[1].Attributes.Add("class", "deleted");`